# How to get user ID from Discord username?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm doing a little project where I take values from a Google sheet with form responses and DM them to specific users. I've already retrieved the user tag (`User#0000`) from the sheet and have stored it in `tag.value`.

When filling out the form, the user checks a box that they are in the server, therefore I'm trying to find the user via my server.

This is the code I've already made but it outputs an error that `guild.members` is `undefined`:

```
const guild = client.guilds.fetch('705686666043457606')
const applicant = guild.members.find((member) => member.name == tag.value);
```

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'find' of undefined

Comment: Are you on v11 or v12 of discord.js?

Comment: 12.5.1 to be exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `guild.members` is undefined because `.fetch()` [returns a promise](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch) and the returned `guild` doesn't have a `member` property.

You either need to use the `.then` method, to access the fetched `guild`:

```js
client.guilds.fetch('705686666043457606')
  .then(guild => {
    const applicant = guild.members.cache
      .find((member) => member.user.tag === tag.value)
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

...or use async/await:

```js
async yourFunction() {
  try {
    const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('705686666043457606')
    const applicant = guild.members.cache
      .find((member) => member.user.tag === tag.value)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Please note that you can only use `await` in `async` functions, so make sure to convert the function where your code is by adding the `async` keyword.

Also, make sure you use the user tag not the username. Find the member by comparing `member.user.tag` in the `.find()` method, and not `member.name`.

Comment: `applicant` comes back `undefined` after logging it in console.

Comment: Oh, it's because you check the `member.name` instead of `member.user.tag`. I've just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In discord.js v12 `members` is a [GuildMemberManager](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) which means you have to use the cache first.

For example:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.fetch('705686666043457606');
const applicant = guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.name == tag.value);
```

`.find()` can be called on a collection, which is what the `cache` is in the GuildMemberManager (i.e. `guild`). You can find more methods for a collection [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection). You could also use the [GuildManagerMember#fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) method available in v12.

Comment: Outputs `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined` using your method.

Comment: @Ralfotr, it's because `guild` is a promise and it doesn't have a `member` property. See my answer.